# Display label in UITableview cell When its visible in Ios

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS. I need to show the Label in timeDelay in `UITableViewCell` only when its visible?

Comment: Please clarify this should be for specific cell or all the cells.

Comment: Specific Cell @SumitGarg

Comment: where you define timeDelay. Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Please show me your cellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `UITableView` cell. In your `cellForRowIndexPath`, call the function `performSelectorWithDelay` which will show your UILabel.

When the `cellForRowIndexPath` is called, it's pretty certain that the cell will now be shown.